# Codec not found for requested operation: [frozen<ynapanalyticsteam.ynapnestedmap> <-> java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>]

Tags: java, cassandra, codec, datastax-java-driver, user-defined-types

I'm  working on data retrieval part of Cassandra using Java Driver.

I have a custom data type

```
CREATE TYPE ynapanalyticsteam.ynapnestedmap (
so_nestedmap map<text, text>
```

);

And column type mapped as below

```
order_line map<text, frozen<ynapnestedmap>>
```

I am trying to retrieve value of this column using TypeToken as below.

```
row.getMap("order_line", TypeToken.of(String.class), new TypeToken<Map<String,String>>() {});
```

But I am still getting codecNot found exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define codec for your nested user-defined type, not for `Map<String, String>` - they are different types...

The [documentation for java driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/custom_codecs/#creating-custom-codecs-for-user-defined-types-ud-ts) has good description of this process.

The code that you trying to use will work for definition of column like:

```
order_line map<text, frozen<map<text, text>>>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for inputs. That helped. I was able to create UDT  and register in codec.